Converting Unity Built In RenderPipeline shader to URP shader
I am working on the Unity Learn 3D Game Kit. But in URP project, shaders are not working as expected. So i have to convert them to URP.Below code is from 3D Game Kit shader. I am not good at shader coding. Anyone, please convert this to URP.
SubShader {
    Tags { "Queue"="AlphaTest" "RenderType"="TransparentCutout" 
          "IgnoreProjector"="True" }
    #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows vertex:vert addshadow 

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    sampler2D _Noise;
    sampler2D _Gradient;
    sampler2D _Normal;
    sampler2D _MetallicSmooth;
    sampler2D _AO;
    half _Glossiness, _Metallic, _Cutoff, _EdgeSize, _NoiseStrength, _DisplaceAmount;
    half4 _Color, _EdgeColor1, _Emission;

    struct Input {
        float2 uv_Noise;
        float2 uv_MainTex;
        fixed4 color : COLOR0;
        float3 worldPos;
    };

    void vert (inout appdata_full v, out Input o) {
        UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input,o);
        float3 pos = mul((float3x3)unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex.xyz);
        pos.x += _Time*30;
        float4 tex = tex2Dlod(_Noise, float4(pos, 0)*0.5);
        float4 Gradient = tex2Dlod (_Gradient, float4(v.texcoord.xy,0,0));
        float mask = smoothstep(_Cutoff, _Cutoff - 0.3, 1-Gradient);
        v.vertex.xyz += v.normal*tex*mask*_Cutoff*_DisplaceAmount;
      }
 
    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
        half3 Noise = tex2D (_Noise, IN.uv_Noise);
        half4 MetallicSmooth = tex2D (_MetallicSmooth, IN.uv_MainTex);
        #if _USE_GRADIENT_ON
        half3 Gradient = tex2D (_Gradient, IN.uv_MainTex);
        half Edge = smoothstep(_Cutoff, _Cutoff - _EdgeSize, 1-(Gradient + Noise.r*(1- 
       Gradient)*_NoiseStrength));
        #else
        half Edge = smoothstep(_Cutoff, _Cutoff - _EdgeSize, 1-Noise.r);
        #endif
        fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
        fixed3 EmissiveCol = c.a * _Emission;
        o.Albedo = c * _Color;
        o.Occlusion = tex2D (_AO, IN.uv_MainTex);
        o.Emission = EmissiveCol + _EdgeColor1 * Edge;
        o.Normal = UnpackNormal (tex2D (_Normal, IN.uv_MainTex));
        o.Metallic = MetallicSmooth.r * _Metallic;
        o.Smoothness = MetallicSmooth.a * _Glossiness;
        clip(1-Edge - _Cutoff);
    }
    ENDCG
     }
     FallBack "Diffuse"
 }


How far did you get? What exactly is the problem? Do you get errors? If so, what are those?

I know nothing about shaders. That's why I posted whole shader.

Did you try using AI tools to do that? Also why are you trying to work with that shader in URP project? Just create normal built-in renderer project or search for URP shaders.

I’m voting to close this question because poster is asking for someone to convert the shader code without any specific question or attempt.
